# How can I reduce the space between the text and the text and the borders of the page?

Tags: margins

What I have:

```
|--text--|
```

What I would like to have:

```
|-textte-|
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please clarify your question and post a screenshot of your output also.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to obtain this is to specify the `margin` key-value using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{geometry,lipsum}

% default
%\geometry{margin=1in}% 1in margin
%\geometry{margin=1cm}% 1cm margin

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The above example shows a change in margin from the default (on left) to 1in (middle) to 1cm (on right).

Note that you may have to consider adjusting the footer/header when using very small margins. However, `geometry` can accommodate for that as well, or set a different vertical margin.

[`typearea`](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea) can also provide support with margin changes as part of the KOMA-script bundle.